# Android convert numbers into date format

Tags: java, android, database, date, simpledateformat

[image: database]I am storing month and year in my android database. I want to fetch it and convert it to date format so that I can match it with current month and year present in array. Im fetching it through ArrayList but how to convert in date format and match?

```
private ArrayList<String> getGspApprovedMonthData() {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>(gspApprovedMonth.size());
    gspApprovedMonth.clear();
    SqlDataStore sd = new SqlDataStore(this);
    sd.open();
    String gspQuery = " SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_GSP_APPROVED_DATA;
    Cursor gspCu = sd.getData(gspQuery);
    if(gspCu.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            String gspMonth = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.GSP_APPROVED_MONTH));
            String gspYr = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.GSP_APPROVED_YEAR));

            gspApprovedMonth.add(gspMonth+gspYr);
        } while (gspCu.moveToNext());
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    for (String dateString : gspApprovedMonth) {
        try {
            dates.add(sdf.parse(dateString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    gspCu.close();
    sd.close();
    return gspApprovedMonth;
}
```

Comment: what you stored in your database can you give example.?

Comment: @Urvish Shiroya - U can refer to the screenshot which I have updated

Comment: First of all consider throwing away the `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes since they were always troublesome and a long outdated. You want to use `YearMonth` and potentially `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: After you have retrieved your strings, you get your `YearMonth` from `YearMonth gspYm = Year.parse(gspYr).atMonth(Integer.parseInt(gspMonth));`. After that you may compare it to current month using for example `gspYm.equals(YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))`.

Comment: @Ole V.V.  - Thanks! works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) in Mar 2014. Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

#### Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:

The `java.time` API provides you with [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) that you can combine with a month using [`Year#atMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#atMonth-int-) to get a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). A `YearMonth` can be compared with another using its methods like [`YearMonth#isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#isAfter-java.time.YearMonth-), `YearMonth#isBefore` etc.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sample year and month strings
        String strYear = "2022";
        String strMonth = "9";
        YearMonth ym = Year.of(Integer.parseInt(strYear))
                           .atMonth(Integer.parseInt(strMonth));
        System.out.println(ym);

        // Comparing two instances of YearMonth
        YearMonth currentYm = YearMonth.now();
        if (ym.isAfter(currentYm))
            System.out.println(ym + " is after " + currentYm);
        else
            System.out.println(ym + " is before or equal to " + currentYm);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09
2022-09 is before or equal to 2023-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eJyVjk)

### How to implement it in your code?

```
List<YearMonth> yearMonths = new ArrayList<>(gspApprovedMonth.size());

// ...

if(gspCu.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        String gspMonth = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.GSP_APPROVED_MONTH));
        String gspYr = gspCu.getString(gspCu.getColumnIndex(Queryclass.GSP_APPROVED_YEAR));

        yearMonths.add(Year.of(Integer.parseInt(gspYr))
                           .atMonth(Integer.parseInt(gspMonth)));
        // ...
    } while (gspCu.moveToNext());
}
// ...
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.